# Холивар по поводу реализации. С++ и Qt

Tags: c++, qt, ооп

Есть объект A который владеет объектом B (объявляется и инициализируется в конструкторе объекта A и является членом объекта A).

Разгорелся настоящий холивар по поводу того, как лучше обеспечить взаимодействие этих двух объектов.

Решения:

- Первое решение предполагает создание у объекта A  Qt-сигнала, а у объекта B публичного слота. И эти сигнал и слот коннектятся в конструкторе объекта A. И при наступлении определенного события объект A сообщает объекту B о наступлении этого события и объект B выполняет определенный алгоритм.
- Второе решение предполагает создание у объекта B публичного метода и при наступлении события в методе объекта A вызывается публичный метод объекта B.

Так вот из-за этого разгорелся нешуточный холивар со влечением в него кучи народу.

Сугубо мое мнение, что это дело вкуса и предпочтения. Что обе реализации ничем не отличаются.

Хотел бы посмотреть, что скажет сообщество по этому поводу. Какие плюсы и минусы у каждой реализации?

Comment: И вы решили уже во вторую тему перенести холивар? :)

Comment: Я на самом деле не понимаю о чем люди спорят) Мне кажется это два одинаковых с технической точки зрения решения. Какие реально есть плюсы и минусы то?

Comment: Мое мнение: если можно напрямую вызывать, то без сигнала. Нет смысла порождать лишние сущности. Сигнал будет полезен, когда нужно соединить два объекта, которые друг от друге ничего не знают. Например, можно использовать QPushButton и свой виджет Foo, так вот QPushButton ничего не обязана знать о Foo и его методах, но при клике на кнопку нужно будет конкретный метод Foo вызвать

Comment: А кроме того "что это порождает лишние сущности" какие еще минусы? Более так сказать ощутимые, например: быстродействие, расходы памяти и т.д.? Может скорость компиляции?

Comment: Если по компиляции, то использование Qt-шных штук займут некоторое времени компиляции -- дело в мета-компиляторе (moc), благодаря которому можно использовать сигналы-слоты и рефлексию. Использование сигнала-слота будет немного тяжелее, чем прямой вызов метода, но разницу такая маленькая, что ее можно не учитывать. Это будет касаться и компиляции, о которой писал.

Comment: Что-то вы тут сферических слонов в вакууме обсуждаете. Можно напридумывать еще 100500 способов взаимодействия двух объектов, но чтобы их сравнивать надо сначала четко определить задачу и задать критерии сравнения. А то так и запрос через RPC сгодится.

Comment: Это два принципиально разных подхода (с технической точки зрения). Почитайте про реализацию механизма сигналов/слотов (откройте генерируемые moc_* файлы и посмотрите их) и такие вопросы отпадут сами собой

Comment: Уточните про второй способ, как именно А узнает о Б, что понимается под событием (объект синхронизации или просто условие)

Answer (score 2):

Отличия есть.

- Во первых, использование Qt подхода позволяет развязать два класса - они могут  ничего не знать друг о дружке. Только порядок аргументов. Иногда это бывает удобно.
- Qt подход позволяет легко отложить выполнение кода (Queued), отложить на какое то время (QTimer) или даже запустить в отдельном потоке.

Минус - завязываемся на Qt.